# How to use class.java from service.jws in an Axis project?

Tags: java, jar, import, axis

I'm building a java web service using Apache Axis 1.4. My `service.jws` is already working well on Tomcat. Now I want to expand this web service, adding more classes which should be used from `service.jws`. The problem is when I create a class on `src` folder, I can't import it from my `service.jws` (located at `WebContent` folder), how can I do it?

By the way, other thing i've tried was to create the classes I need in another project, generated `.jar` and added to lib by configuring buildpath, but from  `service.jws` it can't be imported/recognized. However, the lib from axis, that I've added to path by the same way, can be imported and work fine.

Somebody can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I copied otherproject.jar, that I generated, into WEB-INF/lib in my axis project and added it to buildpath by "import jars" in Eclipse (not "import external jars").